# Route53 DNS Aliased to Cloudfront distribution is resolving to Loopback address at some geographies

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a Route53 record (example.app) that is an Alias for an AWS Cloudfront Distribution that hosts my site.

I have numerous clients reporting that they are getting a timeout when attempting to access example.app in various geographies across the United States. There have been no reported issues in EMEA and APAC.

On an affected machine, using `dig`, I can see that I am able to resolve public IPs that point to AWS PoP servers (Domain name and IPs have been altered)

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> example.app
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41637
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
www.example.app.       IN  A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.app.        60  IN  A   257.257.257.1
example.app.        60  IN  A   257.257.257.2
example.app.        60  IN  A   257.257.257.3
example.app.        60  IN  A   257.257.257.4
;; Query time: 88 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.1#53(10.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Dec 09 09:45:39 EST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 122
```

This all looks healthy, however on attempting to visit example.com in my browser, the connection times out.

I can replicate the timeout with the following cURL.

```
curl 'https://example.app/' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' 
  -v
```

Which returns the following

```
 *    Trying 127.0.0.54:443
 * connect to 127.0.0.54 port 443 failed: Operation timed out
 * Failed to connect to example.app port 443 after 75031 ms: Operation timed out
 * Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to wirewax.app port 443 after 75031 ms: Operation timed out
```

Why is it attempting to connect to `127.0.0.54:443` given that's a loopback address? Any help as to what could be coming on would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does https://dnschecker.org/ resolve example.app to "127.0.0.54" anywhere?

Comment: @DusanBajic `example.app` is not resolving to `127.0.0.54` anywhere on dnschecker.org. All geographies are resolving to public IP addresses.

Comment: If this was reported by one user I would say that their DNS settings are wrong, but you mentioned numerous clients... Do you personally have access to a machine that experiences the issue?

Comment: @DusanBajic. I do have one colleague who can replicate the behaviour (which is where I ran the `curl` and `dig` commands to further debug. Confirmed issues occurring in New York and Texas

Comment: If DNS/dig resolves to correct IP addreses, and curl still tries to connect to 127.0.0.54, that would indicate some local configuration to be the cause. Can your colleague confirm there are no entries in /etc/hosts? Also, try adding `--resolve example.app:443:257.257.257.1` option to your curl test request

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was with the DNS of the ISP (Spectrum). Switching the DNS to google's (8.8.8.8) fixed the issue.